# C - Weird termios behaviour when calling read() function Linux

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, termios

I encountered problem when reading ELM327 chip over serial port.
This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <string.h
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#define DEVICE "/dev/ttyUSB0"
#define SPEED B38400 

int main()
{
    struct termios old_stdio; //save the current port settings
    int tty_fd; //file descriptor for serial port
    int retval, res, n, res2, read1, wri;
    char buf[255];
    char buf2[255]; 

    tty_fd = open(DEVICE, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY );
    if(tty_fd < 0)
    {
        perror(DEVICE);
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("Init 1 complete.\n");

    tcflush(tty_fd, TCIOFLUSH);

    fcntl(tty_fd, F_SETFL, 0);


    if(tcgetattr(tty_fd, &old_stdio) != 0)
    {
        perror(DEVICE);
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("Init 2 complete.\n");

    struct termios newtio;


    if(tcgetattr(tty_fd, &newtio) != 0)
    {
        perror(DEVICE);
        exit(-1);
    }

    cfsetospeed(&newtio, B38400);
    cfsetispeed(&newtio, B38400);

    printf("Init 3 complete.\n");
    newtio.c_cflag |= CLOCAL | CREAD | HUPCL;
    newtio.c_iflag |= ICRNL | IGNPAR;
    newtio.c_lflag &= !(ICANON | ISIG);
    newtio.c_lflag |=  ECHOK | ECHOE | ECHOKE;
    newtio.c_oflag |= ONLCR;

    newtio.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    newtio.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;


    if(tcsetattr(tty_fd, TCSANOW, &newtio) != 0)
    {
        perror(DEVICE);
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("Init 4 complete.\n");


    for(n = 55; n > 0; n--)
    {
                printf("Please enter a command: ");
                (void)fgets(buf2, 255, stdin);
                printf("Ok.input was %s ",&buf2); 
                (void)write(tty_fd, buf2, strlen(buf2));
                (void)write(tty_fd, "\r", 1);
                printf("Ok. Waiting for reply\n");
                res = read(tty_fd, &buf, 255);       
                printf("Read:%d %s \n",res, &buf);              
    }

    //restore the original port settings
    tcsetattr(tty_fd, TCSANOW, &old_stdio); 

        close(tty_fd);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS; //return all good
}
```

I can write to device but after writing `atz` read function isn't reading anything. But after hitting enter `\n` one more time it prints output in terminal.

```
Init 1 complete.
Init 2 complete.
Init 3 complete.
Init 4 complete.
Please enter a command: atz
Ok.input was atz
Ok. Waiting for reply
Read:0  
Please enter a command: 
Ok.input was 
Ok. Waiting for reply
Read:20 atz


ELM327 v1.5

>� 
Please enter a command:
```

Dose anyone have idea why is this happening??

Comment: I think Carriage return problem.. I suggest you please check this issue regarding \n \r \t etc..

Comment: 'newtio.c_lflag &= !(ICANON | ISIG);` looks wrong as `!` is a logical NOT. I think you meant to use `~` for bitwise NOT.

Comment: Setting `c_cc[VTIME] = 0` and `c_cc[VMIN] = 0` in non-canonical input mode sets the tty to polling read mode, so the `read` will return 0 immediately if no data is available.

Comment: regarding: `res = read(tty_fd, &buf, 255);       
                printf("Read:%d %s \n",res, &buf);`  the function: `read()` does not NUL terminate the input.   so the call to `printf()` will invoke undefined behavior.  you need to insert, after the read(), a check that `res` is > 0.  if <0 then handle the error.  If 0 then no bytes read then calling `printf()` will only output what ever is already in the buffer, from the prior call to `fgets()` the call to `printf()` should be preceded by `buf[res] = '\0';`